не запускается python скрипт из PHP на сервере с Wiindows
Не получается вызвать pyton скрипт из PHP.
PHP 8.2.26
Apache 2.4
Windows 11 версия 22H
код PHP:
$path = "<тут длинный путь к python>";
echo exec($path . "/python3 C:/www/colombo.online/v3/classes/cls_mt.py 24");

Выполняется, если запустить PHP из командной строки. При вызове через apache exec возвращает false, а в логе apache появляется запись "Не удается выполнить указанную программу.". На VPS с ubuntu всё работает.

Пользуйтесь docker. Лучше, чтобы на VPS и при разработке одинаковое окружение было. А то еще в куче мест потом съедет.

На ОС Windows лучше использовать popen
function my_exec($cmd) {
    if (substr(php_uname(), 0, 7) == "Windows") {
        pclose(popen("start /B ". $cmd, "r"));  
    } else { exec($cmd . " > /dev/null &"); }
}

Вызов
$path = "<тут длинный путь к python>";
my_exec($path . "/python3 C:/www/colombo.online/v3/classes/cls_mt.py 24");



На ОС Windows лучше использовать popen

Спасибо, буду знать

pclose(popen("start /B ". $cmd, "r"));

Хорошая идея, использовать команду start. К сожалению, не успел попробовать, так как проблема решилась чуть раньше сносом питона из Microsoft Store и установкой с официального сайта. Я заподозрил неладное, когда обратил внимание, что все файлы по <очень длинному пути> имеют размер 0 байт. Какие-то симлинки, а где на самом деле находится python в черном ящике windows, я так и не понял.

добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! стоило опубликовать это как комментарий, а не ответ.
